# Laravel: return bool from custom middleware throttle group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, throttling, laravel-middleware

I want to implement my own custom logics in middleware route group of my Laravel app.

What can I use for now out of the box with Laravel:

```php
Route::middleware('throttle:10,1')->group(function () {
   Route::get('/test/throttle', function() {
      return response('OK', 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
   });
});
```

So, as expected, it returns default 429 code view as HttpResponseException.

---

But I want to override throttle middleware and return just a (bool) `tooManyAttempts` value as function argument:

```php
Route::middleware('customthrottle:10,1')->group(function ($tooManyAttempts) {

   Route::get('/test/throttle', function() {
      if ($tooManyAttempts) {
         return response("My custom 'Too many attempts' page only for this route", 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
      } else {
         return response('You are good to go yet, he-he', 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
      }
   });
});
```

I read [this article](https://bannister.me/blog/custom-throttle-middleware) but I don't know how to override it in that way where I can pass some value as function argument. It may be (bool) `$tooManyAttempts` value or at least (int) `$maxAttempts` value.

---

What method exactly and in a what way should I override to do that?
(`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php`)

```php
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Routing\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Unlimited;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\InteractsWithTime;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use RuntimeException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ThrottleRequests
{
    use InteractsWithTime;

    /**
     * The rate limiter instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter
     */
    protected $limiter;

    /**
     * Create a new request throttler.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter  $limiter
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(RateLimiter $limiter)
    {
        $this->limiter = $limiter;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  int|string  $maxAttempts
     * @param  float|int  $decayMinutes
     * @param  string  $prefix
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $maxAttempts = 60, $decayMinutes = 1, $prefix = '')
    {
        if (is_string($maxAttempts)
            && func_num_args() === 3
            && ! is_null($limiter = $this->limiter->limiter($maxAttempts))) {
            return $this->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter($request, $next, $maxAttempts, $limiter);
        }

        return $this->handleRequest(
            $request,
            $next,
            [
                (object) [
                    'key' => $prefix.$this->resolveRequestSignature($request),
                    'maxAttempts' => $this->resolveMaxAttempts($request, $maxAttempts),
                    'decayMinutes' => $decayMinutes,
                    'responseCallback' => null,
                ],
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string  $limiterName
     * @param  \Closure  $limiter
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException
     */
    protected function handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter($request, Closure $next, $limiterName, Closure $limiter)
    {
        $limiterResponse = call_user_func($limiter, $request);

        if ($limiterResponse instanceof Response) {
            return $limiterResponse;
        } elseif ($limiterResponse instanceof Unlimited) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return $this->handleRequest(
            $request,
            $next,
            collect(Arr::wrap($limiterResponse))->map(function ($limit) use ($limiterName) {
                return (object) [
                    'key' => md5($limiterName.$limit->key),
                    'maxAttempts' => $limit->maxAttempts,
                    'decayMinutes' => $limit->decayMinutes,
                    'responseCallback' => $limit->responseCallback,
                ];
            })->all()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  array  $limits
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException
     */
    protected function handleRequest($request, Closure $next, array $limits)
    {
        foreach ($limits as $limit) {
            if ($this->limiter->tooManyAttempts($limit->key, $limit->maxAttempts)) {
                throw $this->buildException($request, $limit->key, $limit->maxAttempts, $limit->responseCallback);
            }

            $this->limiter->hit($limit->key, $limit->decayMinutes * 60);
        }

        $response = $next($request);

        foreach ($limits as $limit) {
            $response = $this->addHeaders(
                $response,
                $limit->maxAttempts,
                $this->calculateRemainingAttempts($limit->key, $limit->maxAttempts)
            );
        }

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Resolve the number of attempts if the user is authenticated or not.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int|string  $maxAttempts
     * @return int
     */
    protected function resolveMaxAttempts($request, $maxAttempts)
    {
        if (Str::contains($maxAttempts, '|')) {
            $maxAttempts = explode('|', $maxAttempts, 2)[$request->user() ? 1 : 0];
        }

        if (! is_numeric($maxAttempts) && $request->user()) {
            $maxAttempts = $request->user()->{$maxAttempts};
        }

        return (int) $maxAttempts;
    }

    /**
     * Resolve request signature.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    protected function resolveRequestSignature($request)
    {
        if ($user = $request->user()) {
            return sha1($user->getAuthIdentifier());
        } elseif ($route = $request->route()) {
            return sha1($route->getDomain().'|'.$request->ip());
        }

        throw new RuntimeException('Unable to generate the request signature. Route unavailable.');
    }

    /**
     * Create a 'too many attempts' exception.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  int  $maxAttempts
     * @param  callable|null  $responseCallback
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException
     */
    protected function buildException($request, $key, $maxAttempts, $responseCallback = null)
    {
        $retryAfter = $this->getTimeUntilNextRetry($key);

        $headers = $this->getHeaders(
            $maxAttempts,
            $this->calculateRemainingAttempts($key, $maxAttempts, $retryAfter),
            $retryAfter
        );

        return is_callable($responseCallback)
                    ? new HttpResponseException($responseCallback($request, $headers))
                    : new ThrottleRequestsException('Too Many Attempts.', null, $headers);
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of seconds until the next retry.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return int
     */
    protected function getTimeUntilNextRetry($key)
    {
        return $this->limiter->availableIn($key);
    }

    /**
     * Add the limit header information to the given response.
     *
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response  $response
     * @param  int  $maxAttempts
     * @param  int  $remainingAttempts
     * @param  int|null  $retryAfter
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function addHeaders(Response $response, $maxAttempts, $remainingAttempts, $retryAfter = null)
    {
        $response->headers->add(
            $this->getHeaders($maxAttempts, $remainingAttempts, $retryAfter, $response)
        );

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Get the limit headers information.
     *
     * @param  int  $maxAttempts
     * @param  int  $remainingAttempts
     * @param  int|null  $retryAfter
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response|null  $response
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getHeaders($maxAttempts,
                                  $remainingAttempts,
                                  $retryAfter = null,
                                  ?Response $response = null)
    {
        if ($response &&
            ! is_null($response->headers->get('X-RateLimit-Remaining')) &&
            (int) $response->headers->get('X-RateLimit-Remaining') <= (int) $remainingAttempts) {
            return [];
        }

        $headers = [
            'X-RateLimit-Limit' => $maxAttempts,
            'X-RateLimit-Remaining' => $remainingAttempts,
        ];

        if (! is_null($retryAfter)) {
            $headers['Retry-After'] = $retryAfter;
            $headers['X-RateLimit-Reset'] = $this->availableAt($retryAfter);
        }

        return $headers;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the number of remaining attempts.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  int  $maxAttempts
     * @param  int|null  $retryAfter
     * @return int
     */
    protected function calculateRemainingAttempts($key, $maxAttempts, $retryAfter = null)
    {
        return is_null($retryAfter) ? $this->limiter->retriesLeft($key, $maxAttempts) : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is kinda an xy problem, you have already came to the conclusion your middleware needs to return a bool. Isn't your problem more that you need to customize the response when it throttles the request?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think it is pretty straightforward issue, I just have no experience yet to solve such tasks. Also I can't find any reliable example similar to this issue. Furthermore, overriding middleware group for returning a bool value will be the most convenient way for this task. But I will appreciate any advice though, even example with customized throttle response which doesn't break required logics.

Comment: But is the response the problem or what do you want to achieve, without talking about a potential solution?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, one way you can achieve what you do in the controller logic, by instead overwriting the exception in the `Exceptions/Handler.php` class.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ThrottleRequestsException) {
         return response('Too many attempts', 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I right if this will affect all throttle exceptions of all middleware groups? If so, unfortunately, then this does not solve the problem.